# PostgreSQL won't use an index for projection if indexes were used for querying

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, optimization, indexing

I've been running some experiments and the statement in the title seems to be true, I'd like to know if there's a way around that.

Here's an example:

```
CREATE TABLE test ( cond text, v1 integer, v2 integer, v3 integer );
-- Insert millions of rows
CREATE INDEX cond_idx ON test (cond);
CREATE INDEX values_idx ON test (v1, v2, v3);
VACUUM ANALYZE test;
```

Running these queries:

```
-- Uses Index Only Scan on values_idx for projection
SELECT sum(v1), sum(v2), sum(v3) FROM test;
-- Uses Bitmap Index Scan on cond_idx then a Bitmap Heap Scan
-- This is undesirable as it doesn't rely exclusively on indexes
SELECT sum(v1), sum(v2), sum(v3) FROM test WHERE cond = '123';
```

PostgreSQL can effectively combine indexes but it seems only for compound conditions, **is there a way to have PostgreSQL use an index for projection after it used one or more for finding the needed rows?**

An automatic response would be to create a single index with all 4 columns. The thing is this just a minimalistic example. In the real world scenario, the same table would be queried by different columns requiring multi-column indexes for each needed query condition.

UPDATE: Changed the count to a sum to make the example more understandable. Also added more "value" columns.

Comment: Maybe I am oldfashioned, but IMHO a table without a primary key is meaningless. Two loose indices won't change things.

Comment: It might as well have a primary key, it's just not relevant to the example.

Comment: That is your opinion. IMHO it is crucial.

Answer (score 1):

The `count()` aggregate cannot use the index data as input because it counts 1 for every non null value: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-aggregate.html

```
count(expression): 
    number of input rows for which the value of expression is not null
```

On the second query, after index filtering, we don't know which row have a null `value` column.

You just need to add the relevant data into your index and use a multi-column index.

```
CREATE INDEX cond_value_idx ON test (cond, value);
```

This may become clear, once you read the excellent http://use-the-index-luke.com/

Here is an analogy to have a better picture of a PostgreSQL's internals.
You have 1000 regular books and 2 "special" books. The 1000 books are your rows, the 2 other are your indexes.

One of the index book is listing every book shelf and number classified by theme, the other is listing every book shelf and number but classified by author.

Please note that the 1000 books are stored in a huge shelf and that the 2 index books are sitting on your desk, ready to be used.

The problem is that some books are so unique that they not classified by theme (our null values).

If you want to count books that have a theme associated, you only need to pick the "theme" index.
But if you want to count every Gregory Smith's books that have a theme associated, you're going to lookup on the author index for Gregory Smith's books and then pick them up in the shelf to see if they have a theme.

The solution here is a third index book that is listing every book shelf and number classified by author and then by theme. Only then you can answer the question immediately without going to the shelfs.

Note that the order of a multiple-column index is important as you can't answer the same question as easily with an index book classified by theme and then by author.

Comment: Nice explanation. The crucial thing is that the list of all 1000 books by theme is no use to you when you've already narrowed down to 10 books with a particular author - you'd have to read through every page of the index to find where those 10 books fit in, which would be no quicker than going to the shelf and looking at them.

Comment: Thanks for replying, the question was how to achieve this without an index that includes both the condition and the projection. As I said in the end, in a real world scenario the projection will have many columns and there are queries with conditions that rely on different columns as well. Your approach requires an index of condition+projection columns for each needed condition.
PostgreSQL can effectively combine several indexes, but seems like it won't for projections.

Comment: Oh I get it, sorry for the wrong answer. I'm afraid that this feature is not implemented in postgresql already, but even if it were, my guess is that many projections will still use table scans. The reason is that using an index is far from being a free operation. With btrees, my typical index is 1/10~1/5 the size of the actual table, up to the table size itself on rare and extreme cases. This mean that with 5 or more projections, the most efficient solution (memory wise) is a table scan. Either way, it's impossible to use indexes for projections with a where clause, as explained in my answer.